# How to remove the first 18 characters (date & time) from filename?

Tags: php

I need to remove the date and time (all characters until and including the "_") from JPG/PNG files in a folder. All the files look like this:

```
2019_07_31_150349_tcResultBig.png
2019_07_31_161349_dTResultBig.png
etc.
```

At the end the files should be renamed:

```
tcResultBig.png
dTResultBig.png
etc.
```

Reading all the files in a `foreach-loop` works quite well. But I struggle with using a regular expression and the replacing part.

I tried so far the following:

```
<?php
/* current directory */
$dir = ".";
/* find images in current directory and consider different combinations     of filename extensions: jpg, JPG, png, PNG */
$images = glob($dir."/*.[JjPp][PpNn][Gg]");

foreach($images as $image) {                
    preg_match("MY REGEX", $image);
        ....

}   
?>
```

Comment: What is `"MY REGEX"`?

Comment: Just explode the file name and take after 2 in that case array of 4 take 3 to start an rename file with move or recreate

Comment: This is just a wildcard for the regular expression, in order to remove the date and time. But I struggle a bit with understanding regular expressions ;-)

Comment: You don't need regexp, you can use strrpos to get last occurance of `_` and substr to get everything from this position to the end

Comment: @Pavel, but then I just get the substring of the filename, right? I want to rename the filename permanently. I guess I need to save the file again with this substring.

Comment: If you want to skip the first 18 characters, why not use a simple `substr`?

Comment: @DonEnzo yes, you get substring of current filename as you wanted. If you need to rename the file on the server, use php function rename;

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "2019_07_31_150349_tcResultBig.png";
$parts = explode("_", $str);
$image = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

echo "Image: " . $image;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex or explode. If you want to remove the 18 first characters then use the substr() function :

```
$fileName = '2019_07_31_150349_tcResultBig.png';
$fileNameWithoutDate = substr($fileName, 18);
```

Comment: You are making an assumption all the files will have the same name schema. Which is not wise. You need to at least check what you're doing. Since the file name could have < 18 characters.

Comment: @Samuel it is question to OP. Moreover, if structure of date can be diff, he needs another approach

Comment: The question is "How to remove the first 18 characters (date & time) from filename?" so yes I do :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need REGEX for this, You just need explode it by `_` and then get the last one

```
foreach($images as $image) {                
   $xpl = explode('_', $image); 
   $newName = end($xpl);
}
```

Comment: To fix the error `Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference` you will get you  can use `$xpl = explode('_', $image);
            $newName = end($xpl);` to fix it ;}

Comment: @splash58 Its $xpl is an array not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the file names in an array, setting a variable will just overwrite the previous name. It's better to just use `array_map` which will store all the files name in a new array.

Non-loop method:

```
<?php
$dir = '.';
$images = glob("$dir/*.[JjPp][PpNn][Gg]");

$files = array_map(function($image) {
  $name = explode('_', $image);
  return $name[count($name) - 1];
}, $images);
```

Which will result in this:

```
Array ( [0] => tcResultBig.png [1] => dTResultBig.png )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the length of the date/time is always the same you can simply use

```
substr($fname, 18);
```

If you have other files in your folder you could use

```
if ($fname[4] == "_" && substr($fname, -4) == ".png")
```

to check if it is a file you want to process.

If this is not sufficient because there could be files in the folder having a very similar name I recommend a regex.
You could also use

```
explode($fname, "_")
```

and then check the first 4 parts with

```
ctype_digit()
```

. But regex is more beautiful.

You could also check if the date and time in the file name are valid.
So 2019_02_29_... will be ignored because 2019 is not a leap year and so this file must be a different than the ones you want to process. I don't know if regex is capable of checking if a date is valid.

If the date/time is a local time (not UTC) where you have summer and winter time it will get more complex. In Germany on 31 March 2019 the time zone was changed from normal time zone to summer time zone. It means all clocks were changed from 02:00 to 03:00 at night. This means 31 March 2019 02:30 is not a invalid date/time for Germany. You might want to ignore such a file because it has no valid date/time.
If the date/time in your file names have a fixed time zone you don't have to perform this check. :-)